# Used OFFSET in SQL Server 2012 and I need and answer for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to send 1 record at a time to a table (Yes 1 record at a time).
I have used this code to set the `@msg` variable in SQL Server 2012 (it uses OFFSET).

`@msg` is a `XML` variable.

```
WHILE @Rowcount > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @Rowcount = @Rowcount - 1

    SET @msg = '<rptlr>' + (SELECT * FROM Deleted rptlr_d ORDER BY VENDOR
    OFFSET @Rowcount ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS) + '</rptlr>'

    IF @company IS NOT NULL 
       INSERT INTO RPTLR (company, winnam, ddf, action, msg, dsn)
       VALUES (@company, 'APPU', '000354', 'delete', @msg, @dsn)
END
```

I have tried (and getting confused) to set this up in 2008 like.

```
SET @msg = '<rptlr>' + (SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY VENDOR) AS rank,*
    FROM Deleted rptlr_d ORDER BY RANK  WHERE rank = @Rowcount 
    FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS)  + '</rptlr>'
```

This does not like the `WHERE`

Or like this using `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SET @msg = '<rptlr>' + (WITH temp AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY VENDOR)
    AS RowNum,* FROM Deleted rptlr_d )
    SELECT * FROM temp  WHERE @Rowcount = temp.RowNum FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS)
    + '</rptlr>'
```

This does not like the `WITH`

I have also tried a `SELECT * (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply a where clause on a column, you need to use a derived table, with something like this:

```
SET @msg = '<rptlr>' + (select * from (SELECT  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY VENDOR) AS rank,*
FROM #Deleted rptlr_d) X  WHERE rank = @Rowcount 
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS)  + '</rptlr>'
```

The table needs to also have an alias, I used X here. Also, the order by cannot be there because it's not allowed (and since you're returning one row, order by isn't really needed).

Instead of `select *` you probably need to specify the correct columns.

Comment: The OVER (Order by ) has to be there when RANK is used.     Thanks for the Answer it works Fine.     The rptlr table replicates to the web and the data is used as a reference for History - so the Select * is used to get all of the fields in the table.